# Is the elapsed time until the completed event happens indicative for the socket speed?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, sockets, windows-phone-7

I am sending `UDP` messages through a .NET `socket` with the `SendAsync` method.

**The question is:**

What has happened until I get the completed event?

Has the message left the device on the wire? Can the elapsed time be used to judge the outgoing network speed?

**Background:**

I need to know the rate at which I can initiate UDP send operations. If the message would have left the device over the network at the time of the completed event, I would maybe add some buffer and initiate the next send operation. I don't care about lost messages and even about the actual transmission rate. It is just to have a rough idea at what rate I can send my messages out.

Comment: Network speed/throughput/latency is something outside of the control of your code. By the time you've found some "measure" of it, it might have changed (possibly significantly)

Comment: UDP messages do not even guarantee delivery, so, no. You cannot judge network speed, as you cannot even know if the message reach the destination.

Comment: Thanks guys so far. It is more about what happens until the completed event occurs when sending. Is it raised when the bytes have left the device already on the wire? Or has just another OS thread been launched that will perform the actual sending?

Comment: I don't think there's a firm enough contract to know what will or will not have happened (both on current implementations and any future ones - and it may depend on OS versions, drivers, etc). I'd love to know how you planned to use the answer to this question - what would you do differently?

Comment: It is with sockets on windows phone 7.1 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

No, not at all. Not just because you use `UDP`, but more importantly, because you use `SendAsync`. In general, when you use methods that end with **Async** this means they **don't block the current thread** and they will run in the background, so you can't measure when they finish their work. To clarify this more you'd better to study about Multi-Threading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173178%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)."Threading enables your C# program to perform concurrent processing so you can do more than one operation at a time" and generally `Async` methods operate this way i.e. **Asynchronized**. So *you couldn't even find some measure* about the speed this way if you had a sound understanding of this `Async` thing.